# Parse Currency YQL with Jquery

Tags: jquery, json, yql

As I can parse this query YQL using Jquery.
I can not see the information
thank you very much

**Json**

```
    {
 "query": {
  "count": 2,
  "created": "2012-01-25T18:58:01Z",
  "lang": "en-US",
  "results": {
   "span": [
    {
     "id": "yfs_l10_audmxn=x",
     "content": "13.8172"
    },
    {
     "id": "yfs_l10_audmxn=x",
     "content": "13.8172"
    }
   ]
  }
 }
}
```

**Jquery**

```
        <script>
        $(function(){
           $.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fmx.finance.yahoo.com%2Fq%3Fs%3DAUDMXN%3DX%22%20and%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20xpath%3D'%2F%2F*%5B%40id%3D%22yfs_l10_audmxn%3Dx%22%5D'&format=json&callback=", function(data){
               $('#currency').html(data.query['results'].span);
           }); 
        });
    </script>
```

tnks =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The currency information is there. I dont know why you dont see it.
May be you should use this,

```
$('#currency').html(data.query['results'].span[0].content);
```

`data.query['results'].span[0].content` contains `13.8172`.
Thats means   `MXN 1 = AUD 13.8172`

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(function(){
           $.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fmx.finance.yahoo.com%2Fq%3Fs%3DAUDMXN%3DX%22%20and%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20xpath%3D'%2F%2F*%5B%40id%3D%22yfs_l10_audmxn%3Dx%22%5D'&format=json&callback=", function(data){
       $("span").html(data.query.count);
       $("#created").html(data.query.created);
       $("#lang").html(data.query.lang);
$(data.query.results.span).each(function(index,elem){
 $.each(elem,function(k,v){
  $("<tr/>").append("<td> "+k+" </td><td> "+v+" </td>").appendTo("table");
    })
   });
  });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bVhzj/21/)